# Editing text input with static data on react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When using text input using this.state it doesn't matter to give `value` a state variable and you'll able to edit the value, in my case here I am rendering a list and when I specify `value` of text input I can no longer edit that value because it's outside the state, I don't want to use placeholder to show the value, I need a way to have it as value but also be able to edit that value.

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType='decimal-pad'
  value={String(roomData.room_attached_dimensions.depth)}
  onChangeText={(value) => this.handleRoomEdit(value)}
/>
```

Also I don't understand why should I wrap my values with `String`, it shows nothing otherwise.

My list looks like so

```
  const attachedRooms = this.state.rooms_attached.map((item, index) => (
      <View key={index}>
        ...
      </View>
   ))
```

The function does nothing special

```
  handleRoomEdit = (value) => {
    this.setState({ roomEdit: true, value: value })
  }
```

Of course I have different inputs I cannot simply give them different names, the data is stored on `asyncStorage` and even if I edit the array it  dont work unless I re mount the damn component

Comment: Can you add more code? Like what does `this.handleRoomEdit` does? It will be better if you can add code for whole component.

Comment: I added more details, something wrong with that String(...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay there's you error. You are not handling your input's value with state. That's why it does not work. You can do something like this -

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType='decimal-pad'
  value={this.state.value || String(roomData.room_attached_dimensions.depth)}
  onChangeText={(value) => this.handleRoomEdit(value)}
/>
```

I think this should work. Now you are handling your input's value with state. Or you can use defaultValue to give initial value, but I think react discourages using defaultValue and Value both -

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType='decimal-pad'
  defaultValue={String(roomData.room_attached_dimensions.depth)}
  value={this.state.value}
  onChangeText={(value) => this.handleRoomEdit(value)}
/>
```

EDIT:: Also you can use ES6 to make your code clean -

```
  handleRoomEdit = (value) => {
    this.setState({ roomEdit: true, value }) //use ES6 shorthand //
  }
```

Comment: Thanks I think default value is a great suggestion, it worked, I simply cannot specify value as this.state.value because too much variables, it will change all of them

Comment: @usfslk I think you should handle one input with one state value. If you give unique name to them then you can handle all of them using dynamic `[name]` property. Well i am glad it worked for you. Cheers. :)

Comment: I know that name trick I just don't need to update the var on frontend this time, all the data handling is executed on the function